# Invalid command error when running shell script after successfully connect to FTP server

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script to delete the files from FTP server, but when I am running the shell script I am facing "Invalid command" error after successful connection with FTP server.

Below is my script

```
ftp -inv $HOST <<EOS
user $ftp_u $ftp_p
cd /path/to/directory
files=$(find -type f -mtime +3)
for file in $files;
do
delete "$file"
done
quit
EOS
```

Another code snippet to delete files

```
cd /path/to/directory
for file in *; do 
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        days_ago=$(date -d 'now - 1 days' +%s)
        file_time=$(date -r "$file" +%s)
           if [[ $file_time -lt $days_ago ]]; then
            delete "$file"
        fi
    fi
done
quit
```

I tried with above two scripts in both the cases I am getting Invalid command error

I just tried with simple echo something like below, in this case also I got same error.

```
ftp -inv $HOST <<EOS
user $ftp_u $ftp_p
cd /path/directory
for file in *; do 
    if [ -f "$file" ]
       echo “$file”
    fi
done
quit
EOS
```

can someone help me on this.

Comment: You can't put shell commands etc (like `for ... do`, `files=`, `if`, etc) inside a here-document, and expect them to do anything useful. They're just passed literally to the `ftp` program as input, it has no idea what they mean, so you get "Invalid command". The only shell syntax you can use inside a here-document is variable and command substitutions (like `$variable` and `$(command)`). Note that `cd` does work, because it's both a shell command *and* and ftp command.

Comment: what would be the solution in this case, how can I run above script. This is the first time I am writing shell script

Comment: @Hmm : I would create using the shell script a huge string, consisting of all FTP commands to execute, and then have this string being run with ftp. This makes also debugging easier, because you can see what is going to be deleted, before the deletion process actually starts. And, if you are not familiar with bash or shell scripting, you can do this with any other programming language you are comfortable with.

Comment: This is actually quite difficult, since you can't run `find` or `date` (to get the modify time of a file) over an FTP connection; about the only thing you could do is run `ls` (actually the FTP `LIST` command) over the connection, capture the output, parse it to get the dates... yeah, this is going to be a mess. Can you use some more civilized protocol to connect to the server?

Comment: I would coproc the ftp process and feed commands and get output from it, process the output to construct new commands to feed into the ftp process.

Comment: Or use [rclone](http://rclone.org) to mount the ftp server as a local directory and script find on that.

Comment: @Larry I haven't used rclone, but it sounds like a much better option.

Comment: @GordonDavisson - Yeah, I was going to test it out on an FTP server but can't find any public ones anymore!

Comment: @Larry If possible, avoid the FTP protocol entirely -- it was designed before we had any real idea how an Internet protocol should work, and has a bunch of inherent problems. Lack of even the most rudimentary security (plaintext passwords over the Internet) and poor behavior with firewalls are the biggest hangups, but not the only ones.

Answer (score 0):

Here's *an* answer: Install [rclone](https://rclone.org), create a file with **rclone config** with content similar to:

```
$ tail -6 .config/rclone/rclone.conf 
[ftptest]
type = ftp
host = speedtest.tele2.net
user = anonymous
pass = scFur8s95RjyqygFeNA2TAM32HA_pSn6Lw
```

with your host, user, and password, then do something similar to

```
$ go/bin/rclone mount --daemon ftptest: /tmp/m2
$ find /tmp/m2 -type f -mtime +9999 -delete
$ umount /tmp/m2 # on linux: fusermount -u /tmp/m2
```

Comment: As Gordon Davisson rightly points out, avoid the FTP protocol altogether. Rclone uses the FTP protocol for the connection described in this answer, so it's going to pass the password in clear text to your FTP server. If there are un-secured systems between your FTP client and FTP server you will be exposing your password. @Hmm, this may be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), so you might want to define what your higher level goal is.